# Need to split a string stored in a variable into multiple variables

Tags: string, bash

I'm bumping up against the limits of my knowledge here and struggling with this quite a bit.
I have a bash script that produces a user interface dialog (the dialog is produced by a macOS app called SwiftDialog).  Users enter information into text fields and/or from pull down menus. The results are delivered to STDOUT formatted like so:

label : value

example

(As you can see, some of the labels include quote marks, some don't)

```
HMS Asset Tag : hms12345
Room # : 233 
"Organization" : "HMS"
"Organization" index : "0"
"Department" : "Administration"
"Department" index : "4" 
"Location" : "-Work From Home"
"Location" index : "2"
```

I've got STOUT going to a variable called "fullValue", but I need to extract the user entered values into individual variables, something like this:

```
hmsAssetTag: hms12345
roomNumber: 233
organizationName: HMS
departmentName: Administration
locationName: -Work From Home
```

(I don't care about the index values)

I was able to use awk to get hmsAssetTag, but Room # is incorrect. I didn't try any of the others because of the enclosing quote marks, which I have no control over and no idea how to deal with.

```
hmsAssetTag=$(echo $fullValue | awk ' "HMS Asset Tag : " {print $5}' )
roomNumber=$(echo $fullValue | awk ' "Room # : " {print $4}' )
echo "Asset Tag: $assetTagValue"
echo "Room #: $roomNumberValue"
```

What I expected:

```
Asset Tag: hms12345
Room #: 233
```

What I got:

```
Asset Tag: hms12345
Room #: hms12345
```

How can I get those user entered values into their own variables for use later on?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `awk ' "HMS Asset Tag : " {print $5}'` says: if string is not empty or zero, print field 5. Perhaps you meant `awk /HMS Asset Tag :/ { print $5 }'` - if line matches string print field 5.

Comment: `echo $fullValue` performs wordsplitting - every run of whitespace (including newlines) turns into a single space - so awk sees only a single long line. Perhaps you meant `echo "$fullValue"`

Comment: please update the question with the complete output from `typeset -p fullValue` so we can see exactly how the data is stored in `fullValue`

Comment: when you say *`extract the user entered values into individual variables,`* ... are you talking about `bash` variables, `awk` variables, or some other type of 'variable'? or do you just need to print the formatted results to stdout (as in your expected output, eg, `hmsAssetTag: hms12345`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk is a good choice for this, but imo you are missing one crucial point, obviously the delimiter between var name and value in your output is ' : ', use it like this:

```
$ cat file
HMS Asset Tag : hms12345
Room # : 233 
"Organization" : "HMS"
"Organization" index : "0"
"Department" : "Administration"
"Department" index : "4" 
"Location" : "-Work From Home"
"Location" index : "2"

$ awk -F' : ' '/Room/{print "roomNumber:", $2}' file
roomNumber: 233
```

Comment: thank you, this was my missing piece.  It's working as expected now.  This is the end result which is producing the output I was looking for: hmsAssetTag=$(echo "$fullValue" | awk -F' : ' '/HMS Asset Tag/{print $2}' )
roomNumber=$(echo "$fullValue" | awk -F' : ' '/Room/{print $2}' )